# If $-1\leq x, y \leq 1$ and $x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2} = 1$, find $x^2+y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math, radicals

Let $x,\, y\in\mathbb
 R,\ -1\leq x,\, y\leq 1$ such that $x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2} = 1.$

Find the sum $S = x^2+y^2.$

Comment: This is from a contest AND you’ve shown no attempt. I’m voting to close.

Comment: If (and it's a big if) this question is well-posed (depending on the context this may well not be your responsibility), then noting that $x = 0$ and $y = 1$ gives a solution to the initial equation, we must have $S = x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor How do you know this is from a contest?

Comment: SEe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388863/if-arcsin-x-arcsin-y-frac-pi2-prove-that-x2y2-1

Comment: @JavaMan Tagged [contest-math]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=\sin\alpha$ and $y=\sin\beta$, where $\{\alpha,\beta\}\subset[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}].$

Thus, the condition gives $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=1.$

Can you end it now?

Also, we can make squaring twice.

Indeed, the condition gives
$$x^2(1-y^2)+y^2(1-x^2)+2xy\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}=1$$ or
$$2xy\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}=1-x^2-y^2+2x^2y^2,$$ which after squaring again gives
$$1+x^4+y^4-2x^2-2y^2+2x^2y^2=0$$ or
$$(x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2+y^2)+1=0$$ or
$$x^2+y^2=1.$$

Answer (score 4):

I think Michael's solution is much easier, but it's not something most people would think of. Instead, let's try doing this algebraically. First, I am going to isolate one of the terms on the left, so subtract by $y\sqrt{1-x^2}$:
$$x\sqrt{1-y^2}=1-y\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Now, when we square both sides, the square root on the left goes away:
$$x^2(1-y^2)=1+y^2(1-x^2)-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Simplify some terms:
$$x^2-x^2y^2=1+y^2-x^2y^2-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Add both sides by $x^2y^2$:
$$x^2=1+y^2-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Subtract both sides by $1+y^2$ to isolate the square root on the right:
$$x^2-y^2-1=-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Square both sides to get rid of the square root:
$$x^4+y^4+1-2x^2y^2-2x^2+2y^2=4y^2(1-x^2)$$
Simplify some terms:
$$x^4+y^4+1-2x^2y^2-2x^2+2y^2=4y^2-4x^2y^2$$
Add both sides by $4x^2y^2-4y^2$:
$$x^4+y^4+1+2x^2y^2-2x^2-2y^2=0$$
Now, this is kind of hard to notice, but the $x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2$ terms kind of go together because that's $(x^2+y^2)^2$ and the $-2x^2-2y^2$ go together because that's $-2(x^2+y^2)$. If we make these substitutions, we get:
$$(x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2+y^2)+1=0$$
Substitute $S=x^2+y^2$:
$$S^2-2S+1=0$$
Factor and solve:
$$(S-1)^2=0\rightarrow S=1$$

Comment: $x^2=1+y^2-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}\iff 1-x^2+y^2-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}=0\iff (\sqrt{1-x^2})^2+y^2-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}\iff (\sqrt{1-x^2}-y)^2=0\iff\sqrt{1-x^2}=y\implies x^2+y^2=1.$